# How can I prevent video files restarting when entering screensaver in Media Center?

Tags: windows, windows-media-center, screensaver

If I am watching a video file, press stop then wait for the screensaver to kick in, the video file will restart from where it was stopped but the screen will remain blank, i.e. the audio will be playing - annoying.

Although I'm not sure when this started, it has been happening for a while (certainly longer than any system restore points I have) so I'm presuming some update caused this.

Is there anything I can do to stop this, short of a full OS reinstall?

Fully updated Vista Home Premium SP2 with GeForce 7650GS running current WHQL driver.

Edit: Here's a timeline of what happens:

- Playing video normally
- Press stop.  Video & audio stop, play menu appears on screen
  [screensaver delay]
- Screensaver kicks in, video resumes playing automatically but 'behind' screensaver

Edit 2: This doesn't happen with recorded TV, only with playback of other video files.

Comment: The problem arrives with what : Screensaver or sleep/hibernate? Do you mean that there is no video after it, or that the audio doesn't stop during it?

Comment: Updated question. Not sure why I put suspend in there, the system never goes to sleep :/

Answer (score 1):

Is your cursor a non-standard one ?
If yes, try setting it to a normal and simple cursor.

Also, make sure that your system is fully patched (also for optional updates).
And turn off the Media Center screensaver.

**EDIT1**

The following Microsoft Support article may pertain to the problem:
[When you use full-screen mode to watch video in Windows Media Center, the screen saver may start on a Windows Vista-based computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929526)

The workaround is :

- In **Power Options** enable the **Don't require a password** setting
- In **Screen Saver** clear the **On resume, display logon screen** check box

The article [Screensaver of doom](http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-10168_7-6302455-1.html) offers a 3rd one:

- Turn off Fast User Switching

**EDIT2**

Some more ideas:

- Open Windows Media Player and select
  menu Tools -> Options. 
  Check "Allow
  screen saver during playback" under
  the Player tab.
- Don't use a screen saver. 
  Use instead Control Panel -> Power Options to turn off the monitor and/or sleep.

**EDIT3**

Since you say that this doesn't happen with recorded TV, this can be a codec problem.

If you have installed any codecs, singly or in packs, you might try uninstalling and installing another one.

I personally prefer the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm), which also has one of the best installers.

**EDIT4**

A utility for listing all codecs on the computer is NirSoft's [InstalledCodec](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html) :

> InstalledCodec is a small utility
>   displays the list of all Codec drivers
>   and DirectShow filters currently
>   installed on your system. For each
>   component the following information is
>   displayed: Display Name, Type,
>   Disabled Status, Installed/Modified
>   Time, Description, Company Name,
>   Filename, and more...
>  It allows
>   you to easily disable or enable any
>   Codec/DirectShow component or export
>   the list into text/xml/html file.

Comment: Normal cursor (spinning blue circle).  
The screensaver is one of the Windows ones (floating clock text).  
System is pretty much fully updated through Windows Update, including most optional updates.  There are a couple that I've not allowed (updates for Office compatibility etc.) as I've run into problems with them in the past.  Can't see how they would make any difference in this instance though.

Comment: @Lunatik: See my edit.

Comment: Password/logon on resume from screensaver is off already.  Fast user switching is already disabled.

Comment: @Lunatik: See my 2nd edit.

Comment: Just wanted to say IMO, I like http://shark007.net/ as the codec pack. Anyway, that's another option if going k-lite fails.

Comment: I've tried to expunge all traces of the dreaded codec packs (not a fan) and just let ffdshow tryouts take care of things, but I'm sure there are remnants of a codec pack tried in the early days of this machine's life which may be to blame.  +1 for the effort though :)

Comment: @Lunatik: I added a 4th edit that might help.